# HTTPS certificate (SSL)

Tags: ssl, https, web, certificate

Is it possible to create my own SSL Certificate that is trusted in browsers? so if a user enter my website they dont need to trust my website. Just like be professional websites?

i'm using nginx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't create one because you are not a certification authority trusted by browsers.

What you can do though is getting a free one from Let'sEncrypt. You have to renew it every 90 days but you can make this on a cronjob quite easily

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create your own certificate authority, I can't help you. But if you just want a free SSL Certificate, that is pretty easy: You can use Letsencrypt. 
For example if you have SSH Access to your server, you can use [Certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/).

Then just download it for your distribution and type:

`./certbot-auto certonly --webroot -w /var/www/your_web_root -d yourdomain.com`

Then all you need to do is changing your nginx site config so it supports SSL.

You can look at my example on github:

https://github.com/NLDev/dotfiles/blob/master/nginx.conf

This config scores an A+ on the SSL-Labs test.

Or you can use this stripped down version:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name example.com;

    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
    location ~ /.well-known {
           allow all;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl default_server;

    root /var/www/example.com/public_html;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    server_name example.com;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge {
            root /var/www/letsencrypt;
    }

    location ~ /.well-known {
            allow all;
    }
}
```

Replace example.com with your domain and change

`/var/www/example.com/public_html;`

to your webroot.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own self-signed certificate, but it is not trusted by browsers due to absence of root certificate in the browser list. Browsers will only trust on preinstalled trusted root certificate which are issued by third-party certificate authorities.

Each browser uses a different set of certificate authority (CA) certificates. You can check the trusted root certificates for the major browsers.

- Firefox: https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/about/governance/policies/security-group/certs/included/
- Chrome: http://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/root-ca-policy
- Opera: https://certs.opera.com/
- iOs: https://support.apple.com/kb/ht5012

You should get an SSL certificate from trusted certificate authority that recognized by browsers. To install an SSL on your nginx server, you can follow this quick guideline - https://www.ssl2buy.com/wiki/how-to-install-ssl-certificate-on-nginx-server